# Hierarhical navigational model with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, caliburn.micro

I want to achieve the following hierarchical navigation model in a WPF MVVM application:

```
ShellView
    Page1View
       Subpage1View
           Subpage2View
       Subpage3View
    Page2View
        ...
```

Meaning that on Shellview, I have buttons to activate/deactivate Page1View and Page2View. On Page1View has buttons to activate Subpage1View and Subpage3View and Subpage1View has a button to activate Subpage2View.

Where should the subpages be displayed ? Should the navigational model map to a view structure exacly ? I mean, I have a ContentControl (named ActiveItem) on ShellView, where Page1View and Page2View is displayed when activated. Should the Subpage1View be displayed on Shell's ActiveItem ContentControl or on the parent view (Page1View) ?

1. If I should display a subpage on ShellView, then how to activate it properly ? Because the button to activate it is on Page1View not on shell.
2. If I should display a subpage on the parent view (Page1View), then I must create a ActiveItem ContentControl on Page1View and hide it before it's needed. How ? Also I guess parent view scrollbars could become a problem.

Please advise!

Using Caliburn.Micro 1.3, .NET 4, WPF.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I threw a demo together.  I'm not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for.  The thing to remember is `Screens` and `Conductors` can contain `Screens` and/or `Conductors`.  So nesting or doing complex screen composition is pretty straight forward.

This example has a `ShellView` with 2 buttons and a `ContentControl`.  `Page1ViewModel` also has 2 buttons and a `ContentControl`.

Clicking `Page1` or the `Page2` button on the `ShellView` activates the appropriate `Page`.  The same is true once a `Page` is activated, clicking on `SubPage1` or `SubPage2` activates the appropriate `SubPage`.

https://bitbucket.org/dbeattie/cmwpfnavsample/src

Comment: Yes, thanks, but the problem is that I want SubPage to fill the whole Page1. In your example SubPage only fills an control on Page1, but I want it to fill the whole Page1 screen.

Comment: Ah, they can all be in a single content control, the buttons on nested pages would tell the shell to activate a different viewmodel using the EventAggregator.

Comment: Not sure if I understand..Could you provide an example please ?

Comment: I can, I haven't had time but it won't take much to change the one linked to show that.

Comment: I'm still having troubles..how do I pass the ViewModel ?

Comment: @user315648 I updated the sample, basically you can have 1 content control that lives in the Shell and using the EventAggregator send messages to the Shell telling it what screen to activate.

Answer (score 1):

We use sub pages this way:

- Subpage itself is shown in a ContentControl that is in page view. So we have shell view that has a ContentControl to show active page and in this active page, there is another ContentControl to show Active sub page.
- We show list of current page's subpages on the shell view itself (because of layout), so we have ItemsControl that is bound to ActiveItem.Items (provided the ActiveItem is page inherited from Conductor).

So we simply use ItemsControl to choose which page or subpage is the currently active and then use ContentControl to show it. Note that selected subpage is shown through its parent page view.

But basically, it is up to you whether you show subpages directly on shell view (ContentControl bound to ActiveItem.ActiveItem) or use another way.

Although subpages are not included, [Coproject](http://coproject.codeplex.com/) sample application might help you. I plan to make it more complex and add subpages later.

ad 2. I don't think you need to hide the ContentControl -if no subpage is selected, it will be empty. Nevertheless, if you want to hide it, I'd suggest using of ValueConverter (from object to Visibility, if object == null then Visibility.Collapsed, otherwise Visible) and bind the ActiveItem ContentControl's Visibility property to ActiveItem again.